# while a date is not within a start and end date swift

Tags: swift, while-loop, nsdate

I have the following code which checks if a selectedDate is within a start and end date. I want to know how to go about saying while the date is NOT within the 2 dates however I don't know how to go about it. I tried using '!==' however it says 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context'

```
while newStartDate.compare(selectedDate) == .OrderedAscending && newEndDate.compare(selectedDate) == .OrderedDescending {
     print("\(selectedDate) is within \(newStartDate) & \(newEndDate)")     
}
```

Comment: the code works fine with xcode 7.3 / swift 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about ?

```
while newStartDate.compare(selectedDate) == .OrderedDescending || newEndDate.compare(selectedDate) == .OrderedAscending {
   print("\(selectedDate) is within \(newStartDate) & \(newEndDate)")
}
```

The selected date has to be before the start date or after the enddate.

Answer (score 0):

I think JulianM's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36198122/5327882) is right. In my opinion to make it more readable, you can use your first try with `!=`:

```
while newStartDate.compare(selectedDate) != .OrderedAscending || newEndDate.compare(selectedDate) != .OrderedDescending {
    print("\(selectedDate) is within \(newStartDate) & \(newEndDate)")
}
```